# How to configure gettext with Yii::t() in Yii2 advanced?

Tags: php, yii, gettext, multilingual, yii2

I'm installed Yii2 advanced template and configure Yii::t() with PhpMessageSource, but i need configure it with GettextMessageSource. I'm added to common/config/main-local.php this code:

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\GettextMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@app/messages',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Put at frontend/messages/ru-RU app.po file sample text:

```
msgid "TEST"
msgstr "Текст"
```

Add in view file:

```
Yii::t('app', 'TEST');
```

But it doesn't work, where i need to store .po files or what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'basePath' => '@app/messages',
```

change to
`'basePath' => '@common/messages',` or `'basePath' => '@root/common/messages`

and replace your messages to common/messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had also problem with GettextMessageSource. Check your po file if it has line msgctxt
It should look like this:

```
msgctxt "app"
msgid "Settings"
msgstr "Ustawienia"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass a parameter it Yii::t()

```
Yii::t("app", "some text: {someVariable}",["someVariable"=>$whatEverYouWant]))
```